# Extracting data from xml format in python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree, nmap

I have the following nmap output as xml format:

```
<ports><extraports state="closed" count="991">
<extrareasons reason="conn-refused" count="991"/>
</extraports>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="22"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="ssh" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="25"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="smtp" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="139"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="netbios-ssn" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="443"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="https" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
```

I want to get port numbers that are open:

```
print 'Port Number: '+host.find('ports').find('port').get('portid')
```

But the result is just `22`.

How can I have the results:

```
22
25
139
443
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find all `port` elements, and get `portid` attributes.

Using [`Element.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> root = ET.fromstring('''
<ports><extraports state="closed" count="991">
<extrareasons reason="conn-refused" count="991"/>
</extraports>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="22"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="ssh" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="25"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="smtp" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="139"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="netbios-ssn" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
<port protocol="tcp" portid="443"><state state="open" reason="syn-ack" reason_ttl="0"/><service name="https" method="table" conf="3"/></port>
</ports>
''')
>>> [port.get('portid') for port in root.findall('.//port')]
['22', '25', '139', '443']
```

Comment: @MortezaLSC, Iterate the `port` elements: `for port in root.findall('.//port'): print('port: {}'.format(port.get('portid')))`

Comment: I am really sorry...but I do `state=[port.get('state') for state in root.findall('.//port')]` for checking states and then it doesn't return me `open` and say `none`

Comment: @MortezaLSC, `state` attribute is not an attribute of `port` element, but an attribute of `state`. You need to use this: `[port.get('state') for port in root.findall('.//port/state')]`